# My pip isn't working, for both versions of python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

so i have installed both python 2.7 and python 3.8 however in the cmd if i type one of these:

> pip install
>
> pip --version

it uses the python 2.7 version. I don't think that i can use the packages installed with python 3.
i have tried:

> - Reinstalling python (2 & 3)
> - Adding it to my PATH
> - Changing the directory that it is saved in
> - Pip3 commands
> - bootstraping pip

yet none have worked.(also im on windows 7, and require the pip and python for both 2.7 & 3.8)

when i use:

> python3 -m pip install x

or

> py -3 -m pip install x

it comes up with:

> DLL load failed while importing pyexpat: the specified module could
> not be found

Comment: What didn't work? Do you have an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 command in Windows is `python3`. So if you want to run pip with python 3 you have to do `python3 -m pip install`.

You can also replace Python 2 path in your [Path variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)#:~:text=PATH%20is%20an%20environment%20variable,has%20its%20own%20PATH%20setting.) to your Python 3 path, like so when you'll run `python` command it will use Python 3 directly.

Hope i got useful.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the official document,

https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html?highlight=pip#work-with-multiple-versions-of-python-installed-in-parallel

if you are on windows you can use,

```
py -2   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 2
py -2.7 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 2.7
py -3   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 3
py -3.4 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.4
```

On Linux, Mac OS X, and other POSIX systems, use the versioned Python commands in combination with the -m switch to run the appropriate copy of pip:

```
python2   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 2
python2.7 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 2.7
python3   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 3
python3.4 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.4
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you install both `versions` of `python` then by simply entering `pip` command will run that python `pip` whose `path` comes first. You could use `pip3` for pip corresponding to `python3` and `pip2` for pip corresponding to `python2`. But the recommended way is to do following:

For Python 3

```
py -3 -m pip install
```

For Python 2

```
py -2 -m pip install
```

Comment: it comes up with: DLL load failed while importing pyexpat: the specified module could not be found

Comment: Apparently `Python 3.8` has issues with `windows`. Uninstall it and try installing `Python 3.7`. For further reading you can look at https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/990